# jQuery .ajax 'success' function never runs

Tags: ajax, jquery

I am trying to use jQuery for the first time, and my POST function using .ajax is giving me grief.
The POST is successful; my PHP page runs the MySQL query correctly and the newly created user ID is returned. The only problem is that instead of running the 'success' function; it simply loads the PHP page that I called, which simply echoes the user ID.

Here's the jQuery function:

```
function register() {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'sendRegistration.php',
    data: dataString,
    datatype: 'html',
    success: function(response){alert(response);},
    complete: function(response,textStatus){console.log(textStatus);},
    error: function(response){alert(response);}
});
}
```

... and the PHP return stuff:

```
    // Create a new send & recieve object to store and retrieve the data
    $sender = new sendRecieve();
    $custId = $sender->submitUser($userVars);
    if ($custId != 0) {
        echo $custId;
    } else {
        echo "Database connection problems...";
    }
```

The database object is created, and then the php page from the 'url' parameter loads, displaying the id that the $sender->submitUser() function returns.

Ideally, I would like it to never display the 'sendRegistration.php' page, but run another js function.

I'm sure there's a simple solution, but I've not been able to find it after hours of searching.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is this (in) a `submit` handler? Did you prevent the default action?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are likely handling this from a form. If you don't prevent the default form submittal process of the browser, the page will redirect to the `action` url of the form. If there is no `action` in form, the current page will reload, which is most likely what is happening in your case.

To prevent this use either of the following methods

```
$('form').submit(function(event){
    /* this method before AJAX code*/
    event.preventDefault()    

        /* OR*/

      /* this method after all other code in handler*/
      return false;
})
```

The same methods apply if you are sending the AJAX from a click handler on the form submit button

Comment: That sure was the problem; it was running through the classic post process. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

how are you calling the register() function?  It could be the form is being submitted traditionally, you might need to prevent the default action(standard form submit).

Comment: Question answers should be comments. Apart from that - I was going to write the same (but longer).

Comment: I'm calling the register() function from the forms 'onsubmit' property inline:    <form action="sendRegistration.php" method="post" onsubmit='register()'>